# An appropriate way to let users of a module to override certain functions in Python

Tags: python

I'm developing a Python module which would be pip installed into end user's environment. For part of my module, I would like to let the user override with some functions so that the system would be tailored to specific end-user's infrastructure.

For example, we might want users to specific some rule to determine the name of an s3 bucket. Basically somehow, let user define a function like the following:

```
def determine_s3(var1: str, var2: str) -> str:
    if var1 == "banana":
        return "fruits_s3_bucket"

    if var2 == "dog":
        return "animals_s3_bucket"

    return "others_bucket"
```

So different users of my module might have different aforementioned rules. They would have the same input arguments though (i.e. in this example, `var1` and `var2`).

I also don't want to pass `var1` and `var2` everywhere when I need to use s3 because this is kinda static.

How can I setup my module to implement this in Python appropriately? Thanks.

P.S. In Java, I would probably let the user pass in a class name like "com.example.SomeClass" as a config and as long as the corresponding jar is on the classpath, it should work, but I'm not sure how to do that in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Allow users to pass a custom function of their own and return the result of that with the arguments given to `determine_s3`.

```
from typing import Callable

def determine_s3(var1: str, var2: str, user_func: Callable[[str, str], str]) -> str:
    return user_func(var1, var2)

def sample_func(var1: str, var2: str) -> str:
    if var1 == "banana":
        return "fruits_s3_bucket"

    if var2 == "dog":
        return "animals_s3_bucket"

    return "others_bucket"

print(determine_s3("banana", "apple", sample_func))
```

Output:

```
fruits_s3_bucket
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is `sample_func` is something provided by the user later, probably in the user's environment. At my module development time, I won't have access to it. Thus, at places where I need the value, like in your `determine_s3` function, there is nothing I can pass in.

Comment: @WZH “Thus, at places where I need the value, like in your determine_s3 function, there is nothing I can pass in.” It determine_s3 is called internally by your library then you should have the user give you a function when they start using the library **that you store in memory** and then pass to determine_s3 later. I promise you that anywhere you want to use a class there is an easy way to use just a method instead.

Comment: For example, when the user creates an instance of your library’s class, they give their custom determine_s3 function as an argument to the class which you then store for future use.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should create an abstract class with the abstract method `determine_s3`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
 
class BucketSelector(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def determine_s3(self, var1: str, var2: str) -> str:
        pass
```

And you'd use it in your library:

```
def do_something(bucket_selector: BucketSelector):
    bucket = bucket_selector.determine_s3(var1, var2)
```

The user would need to inherit that class with his implementation of `determine_s3`:

```
from your_beautiful_module import do_something, BucketSelector


class MyBucketSelector(BucketSelector):
    def __init__(self, banana):
        self.banana = banana

    def determine_s3(self, var1: str, var2: str) -> str:
        if var1 == self.banana:
            return "fruits_s3_bucket"
    
        if var2 == "dog":
            return "animals_s3_bucket"
    
        return "others_bucket"

do_something(bucket_selector=MyBucketSelector('banana'))
```

This would be a very explicit and versatile solution.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way not to pass this `bucket_selector` to every calling functions, as it's kinda static. Also sometimes it contextually doesn't fit to the calling function. For example, I could have a function called `check_memory_usage` and within this function, it needs to `determine_s3` in a very edge case branch of code. In this case, calling `check_memory_usage` that requires a `bucket_selector` argument is kinda contextually doesn't fit. Developers who are using `check_memory_usage` might be wondering why do I need to provide a `bucket_selector` to `check_memory_usage`?

Comment: It can have a default value (say `None`) in `check_memory_usage`: `def check_memory_usage(required_arg, bucket_selector=None): ...`. Then user won't need to pass it. If it is static/constant, you might want to have it as a class field and `check_memory_usage` as this class' method: `def check_memory_usage(self, required_arg): bucket = self.bucket_selector.determine_s3(var1, var2)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a config file is typically what people would do.

Yes, I know it doesn't exactly follow your var1 and var2 example, but the use of 2 vars to point to 1 s3 bucket is somewhat unclear to me, though the mechanism could be extended to cover multiple vars, **if the logic remained the same for each user**.

(I used json here as it is builtin, but yaml or toml might be better fits for end user configuration).

###### test.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import json
import sys

if len(sys.argv) >=2:
    var1 = sys.argv[1] 
else:
    var1 = ""

def determine_s3(var1: str, config: Path|None =None) -> str:

    pa = Path(config) if config else Path('~/config.json').expanduser()
    with pa.open() as fi:
        config = json.load(fi)

    res = config.get("buckets",{}).get(var1) or config["default_bucket"]
    print(f"determine_s3({var1=})=>{res}")

determine_s3(var1)
```

###### ~/config.json:

```
{
    "buckets" : { 
        "banana": "fruits_s3_bucket",
        "dog": "animals_s3_bucket"
        
    },
    "default_bucket" : "others_bucket"
}
```

##### ouput:

```
% py test.py banana
determine_s3(var1='banana')=>fruits_s3_bucket
% py test.py dog   
determine_s3(var1='dog')=>animals_s3_bucket
% py test.py    
determine_s3(var1='')=>others_bucket
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using the `determine_s3` function as an example. The actual logic could be complicated and would not be able to be generalized. That's why users have to provide their own functions.